# Openstack swift, which url to use in my use case?

Tags: openstack, openstack-swift

I'll be using swift as like S3, where it will host number of files for my site.
I've set my container as public, and so
Here is the URL for a file.

https://provider/v1/auth_1293kdfj/folder/file.mp4

There are two problems:

1. Is it correct in using above format uri in public setting? It feels kinda dangerous because it has the auth_bit.
2. If I visit https://provider/v1/auth_1293kdfj/folder/ it lists all files/bojects in container `folder`. I wish to turn this off, how would I do so? Should I make my container private and assign temp url to ALL objects?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - Yes. It's correct. Probably your authentication server is protected behind a firewall. This is just the project id.  However if you are really worried about security you can configure your webserver to hide this info.

2 - Probably your container has the following acl:

```
.r:*,.rlistings
```

If you set by yourself (what I believe is the most common) you should change it just to:

```
.r:*
```

Comment: My friend told me of this earlier today. Exact answer. Thank you.